# How can I search my git history for a string and change all occurrences?

Tags: git, github

For a password, for example...

I can find all the occurrences of "`my_top_secret`" with:

```
git grep my_top_secret $(git rev-list --all)
```

How can I change them all, e.g. with `--filter-branch` and `--tree-filter` to change `my_top_secret` to be `not_top_secret_now`

so I really remove the references from anyone who clones the repo after this point (or searches github).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a repo I can test this with, but you would basically run a filter branch on all your commits, and then for each commit search for the string and replace any instances that are found.  You'll probably need to fix the sed quoting.

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git grep -n my_top_secret | xargs sed -i 's/my_top_secret/not_top_secret_now/g' ' -- --all
```